# Has anyone implemented HMS map kit of Huawei with Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to find a code sample of how to implement the HMS map kit of huawei with vuejs. But I don't find any information about it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What's a map of Huawei?

Comment: Hi Phix, I mean the HMS map kit of Huawei for being implemented with vuejs

Answer (score 0):

HMS do not have API's to support Vuejs yet, however it may have them supported in near future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Huawei JavaScript Map API instead:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/javascript-api-introduction-0000001050164063-V5